# Shinydashboard UI - boxes and columns

Tags: user-interface, shiny, shinydashboard

Is it possible to have columns within a box in the UI? I have a serval inputs and I want all of them to be in a box but side by side (and not in separate row for each input)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to have columns within a box in the UI.

You can have a look at the following code:

```
library("shinydashboard")

body <- dashboardBody(
  box(title = "Box",
      width = 12,
      status = "warning", 
      solidHeader = TRUE, 
      collapsible = TRUE,
      column(width = 6, plotOutput(outputId = "Plot1")),
      column(width = 6, plotOutput(outputId = "Plot2"))
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
  plot(rnorm(10))
  })

  output$Plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(20))
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    body
  ),
  server = server
)
```